# Text manipulation in powershell

Tags: powershell, script, regex, xml

I'm new to powershell scripting, but managed to put together some lines of code shown below.

```
$input_path = 'C:\Users\ND04805\Documents\1_Projects\10_IP21_Graphics_update\graphic_xml.xml'
$output_file = 'C:\Users\ND04805\Documents\1_Projects\10_IP21_Graphics_update\tags.txt'
$regex1 = '\btag="[A-Za-z_0-9]+\b"'
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex1 -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
$regex2 = 'tag="[A-Za-z]_'
$(Get-content $output_file) -replace $regex2,'' | set-content $output_file
$(Get-content $output_file) -replace '_','(' | set-content $output_file 
$(Get-content $output_file) -replace '"',')' | set-content $output_file
```

**Input file**

- [XML](http://paste2.org/yZIOngAg)

**Output file**

```
dc(1730)
DC(2103)
dc(2416)
DC(2018)
DC(2017)
dc(2026)
dc(2070)
DC(2071)
dc(2100)
dc(2101)
dc(2440)
ac(2773)
ac(2763)
dc(2416)
ac(2829)
dc(2440)
ac(2859)
ac(2879)
ac(2880)
tag=)()
```

**Code Objective**

I have an XML file (graphic_xml.xml) which depicts a process graphics in XML format. There is a string `tag="x_yy_nnnn` which is of interest and I need to extract the same from this XML file.

where

- x and y are alphabets [a-zA-Z]
- nnnn is a 4 digit number

After extracting the tag which looks like `tag="x_yy_nnnn"`, I want to get rid of the `tag="x_` part and changing the remaining stuff so that the tag looks like this `CG yy(nnnn)`.

**Working**

The regex1 will pick the tag from the XML file and pass it on to the output file using the `select-string` cmdlet.

I have put in some ugly replace texts which replace the contents of the output file on every pass

**Question**

I would like to know how this can be done more effectively and correctly. For example, I'm unable to add the `CG<space>` in the beginning of each line of the file. How can this be done?

**Update**

I changed the last line from
`$(Get-content $output_file) -replace '"',')' | set-content $output_file`
to
`$(Get-content $output_file) -replace '"',')' | Foreach-object {"CG $_"} | set-content $output_file`
and got the `CG` string appended to beginning of each line

Comment: Don't require others to download files with thousands of lines, supply a **minimal, complete and  verifiable example** instead.

Comment: I was unable to add the input file into the question (minimal), The question changed like a math question with all symbols and so. That is why I just gave the link to the input file

Comment: Minimal in this sense means a sample with some patterns with context - not the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a more complex RegEx it isn't that difficult:

```
$input_path = '.\graphic_xml.xml'
$output_file = '.\tags.txt'

[RegEx]$Pattern = '(?smi)^.*tag="[A-Z]_([A-Z]{2})_(\d{4}).*$'

Select-String -Path $input_path  -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    "CG $($_.Matches.Groups[1].Value)($($_.Matches.Groups[2].Value))"
  } | Set-Content $output_file
```

Sample output:

```
> Get-Content .\tags.txt |select -first 15
CG dc(1730)
CG DC(2103)
CG dc(2416)
CG DC(2018)
CG DC(2017)
CG dc(2026)
CG dc(2070)
CG DC(2071)
CG dc(2100)
CG dc(2101)
CG dc(2440)
CG ac(2773)
CG ac(2763)
CG dc(2416)
CG ac(2829)
```

You can play with the [RegEx parameters here](https://regex101.com/r/KASk01/1)

Comment: Would it be possible to explain how your regex works? I'm unable to understand the `'(?smi)^.*` part

Comment: Also, the `($_.Matches.Groups[1].Value)($($_.Matches.Groups[2].Value)` should actually return the first alphabet and the second pair of alphabets, but it is returning the second pair of alphabets and the number. How does this work here?

Comment: The `(?smi)` specifies modifiers to the regex, see [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). The parentheses in the regex mark the groups which are referenced by `$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value` - since this is inside a string expression it has to be enclosed with an additional `$()` to force evaluation.

Comment: I tried this a got some errors. Pasting one such instance of the error. `Cannot index into a null array.
At line:7 char:19
+ $_.Matches.Groups[ <<<< 1].Value
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Comment: The code above works here with your complete xml file. What data gives the error?